# Regex to extract Spotify Artist ID from URL string

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following string of a url:

```
https://open.spotify.com/artist/7Ln80lUS6He07XvHI8qqHH?si=75tvlB1pQsW7xomeFfpGQA
```

I need to extract the `7Ln80lUS6He07XvHI8qqHH` part of it. How do I do this with regex in Swift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it like so:

```
let str = "https://open.spotify.com/artist/7Ln80lUS6He07XvHI8qqHH?si=75tvlB1pQsW7xomeFfpGQA"

guard let urlComponents = URLComponents(string: str),
    let artistID = urlComponents.path.split(separator: "/").last
    else {
    fatalError("Can't find the artist")
}

let artistIdString = String(artistID)  //"7Ln80lUS6He07XvHI8qqHH"
```

Or more concisely:

```
guard let urlComponents = URLComponents(string: str) else {
    fatalError("Can't find the artist")
}

let artistID = (urlComponents.path as NSString).lastPathComponent  //"7Ln80lUS6He07XvHI8qqHH"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `lastPathComponent` of `URL` to get the required result, i.e.

```
let str = "https://open.spotify.com/artist/7Ln80lUS6He07XvHI8qqHH?si=75tvlB1pQsW7xomeFfpGQA"

if let url = URL(string: str) {
    print(url.lastPathComponent)
}
```

It will give the last element of the `pathComponents` array of a `URL`.